PC was hanging, "Physical Volumes: not OK (BAD)"
PC repeatedly got stuck, froze.
Restarted it with alt+print screen+r e i s u b. It immediately froze again.
After another start up, I chose a recovery mode¹ and in there the option system-summary.
Under ===LVM state=== this was shown:
*Physical Volumes: not OK (BAD)*

*Volume Groups: OK (good)*

PC runs on ubuntu 22, maybe 24 already.
¹) see https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/1*qm3DD1pRygY9oaPY9jIFoQ.png
Seems as if something is wrong with the harddisk.
How can I check what's wrong and how I can prevent data loss?

Before running any repair or recovery tools, I would first try to backup all my important data.
You can try to back up all important data using rsync, and/or directly clone the entire disk, if possible, with dd, ddrescue or other tools to a new/other drive.
Check this posts:
Comparison of disk cloning software
Cloning data from a damaged SSD

When creating a disk image of an existing system, you should do it with a separate operating system, not while the system is running, as this could introduce errors.

Use a live system or another GNU/Linux distribution for backups and analyses.
There are various options to run dd and ddrescue.
The difference between dd and ddrescue is that ddrescue is specifically designed for data recovery, skipping or retrying bad sectors, while dd simply copies everything block by block without error handling (I would prevent dd from stopping on errors).
With these tools, you can search for errors, repair or recover lost data, and there are even a lot more:
smartctl  | Check disk health using SMART data
pvdisplay | Check the state of the physical volumes
badblocks | Scan for bad sectors on a disk
e2fsck    | Check and repair ext-based filesystems
lvm       | commands (like lvconvert or vgchange)For managing and repairing LVM volumes
gparted  | GUI tool for managing disk partitions and filesystems
testdisk | Recover lost partitions and repair filesystem issues
photorec | Recover lost files from damaged disks or partitions
Edit:
The freeze could also be a problem with the motherboard, your RAM, or an issue with drivers, faulty system configuration, a problem with your display manager, or some drivers.
Errors don’t only occur in the data area, your hardware itself could have issues due to age or other factors, like physical or virtual failures. Otherwise, if everything runs error-free, that’s great
Usually, a combination of different tools, like the list above and others, is used to analyze errors, and not every report is 100% accurate
Here is another list of tools for hardware testing, like motherboard, ram, etc..:

lm-sensors | Monitors temperature, voltage, fan speed of various hardware components, including the motherboard

memtest86+ | Tests the RAM for errors

hardinfo | Information about hardware components, including the motherboard and ram

inxi | Provides detailed system information, including hardware components

hwinfo | Detailed information about hardware components

stress | Stress test your cpu and ram

gsmartcontrol | Graphical interface for smart data, to check the health of storage devices


No matter what you do, even if your system has 0% errors, you should always have backups of your most important data, that’s obvious ^^.

Thanx!
I'm planning to backup some data in the cloud (with nextcloud), disksizes are larger than current cloud account allows for.
Both short and long test with smartctl, for both SSD and HDD went well: "Completed without error".
On with pvdisplay now.

pvdisplay: "Cannot use ... device is partitioned", for both SSD and HDD.

badblocks, read-only: "0 bad blocks found", for both SSD and HDD. Not sure whether write test is wise (surely takes longer), still without backups.

Finally took some time to further investigate pc (still no backup, figuring out how to use nextcloud).
In syslog, before freezing, a series of this message are logged:
"TRAP_PROP - TP 0 - Unknown CUDA fault".
Not sure if it's the same as "Problem with nouveau driver and Ubuntu 24.04".
But coming days I will try the suggested solution* and add GSK_RENDERER=gl to /etc/environment.
*) for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/1bnjx22/gnome_apps_do_not_show_text_unless_fullscreen/
